# Why is my init.m not loading at startup?

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories, kernel-startup, initialization, autoload

The contents of **init.m** are placed inside an *Initialization Cell* so that some symbols are created in the `` Global` `` context and to prepend alternate paths to `$Path` for easier management of files during development. I know the code works because I tested it from within a regular notebook (extension nb) then I compared the output of `setPaths[]` with the raw `$Path` and all path elements matched. I also loaded an arbitrary test package after evaluating `setPaths[]` which would only be possible after `$addpaths` (a short list of directory paths) were prepended to `$Path`. Problem is that Mathematica completely ignores it.

The contents of *Initialization Cell* inside **init.m**:

```
$addpaths = {
   $home = "D:\\Google Drive\\005 Projects\\mathematica\\",
   $packages = FileNameJoin[{$home, "resources", "packages"}]
   };

Options[setPaths] = {show -> True};
setPaths[p_List : $addpaths, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{$path, pos},
   If[TrueQ[OptionValue[show]], fn = Echo, fn = List];
   Map[If[! MemberQ[$Path, #], PrependTo[$Path, #], Null] &, p];
   $path = $Path;
   pos = Sort[Flatten[Map[Position[$Path, #] &, p], 1]];
   $path = MapAt[Style[#, RGBColor[.5, .75, 1], Bold] &, $path, pos];
   fn[pos, "positions of $addpaths -> "];
   fn[Iconize[Column[$path], "$Path"], "new $Path -> "];
   ];
setPaths[];
```

I saved **init.m** to two locations:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]

(* same as *)

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Kernel\\init.m"

FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd", "init.m"}]

(* same as *)

"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\FrontEnd\\init.m"
```

The *test code* for evaluating an arbitrary package **testpack.m**:

```
FindFile["testpack.m"]
Get["testpack`", Path -> $packages]
Echo[$ContextPath, "$ContextPath ->"];
testpack[];
```

Here is the results of evaluating *test code* as Mathematica starts but before evaluating `setPaths[]`:

```
$Failed
Get::path: $packages in $Path is not a string.
Get::path: $packages in $Path is not a string.
Get::noopen: Cannot open testpack`.
$Failed
$ContextPath ->  {DocumentationSearch`,ResourceLocator`,System`,Global`}
testpack[]
```

Here is the results of evaluating *test code* after evaluating `setPaths[]`:

```
"D:\\Google Drive\\005 \
Projects\\mathematica\\resources\\packages\\testpack.m"
"testpack[] loaded successfully"
$ContextPath ->  {testpack`,DocumentationSearch`,ResourceLocator`,System`,Global`}
"testpack[] loaded successfully"
```

**Question: Why isn't my init.m not loading?**

Comment: The output of `FindFile["testpack.m"]` is `$Failed`, indicating that the file has not been found. Type `$Path`. This gives you the locations that MMA searches for a file. A simple solutions would be to specify the whole path in `Get`

Comment: @DanielHuber I already know all that. If you examine my test code you will see i did `Get["testpack`", Path -> $packages]` and it worked but only after I invoked it after I did `setPaths[]`. But it still doesn't answer my question as to why **init.m** isn't loading. BTW I also tried **$UserBaseDirectory\Autoload** and that didn't work either.

Comment: I meant something like: `Get["c:/abc/def/testpack.m"]`

Comment: @DanielHuber i figured out why it wouldn't on another post a user suggested making init a package.

Comment: Good to hear this.